# get the time taken to complete an aws cli command

Tags: aws-cli

Is there a way to add in a parameter to `aws s3 cp` command to output the time taken to copy a file up to s3 or copy down a file to localhost? Can it output something like `TimeTaken: 17 secs` after the task is completed?

Answer (score 3):

you can just use the bash time command:

```
time aws s3 ls
```